# Javascript client fails to connect to SignalR end point

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

Dear Programming Gurus,

I am working of signalr project using .NET CORE on the backend and ReactJS on the front end.
It works on my local machine, but when i tried them on development server somehow the font end
site giving me an issue. If you look at the first picture, we can see the signalr end point response perfectly via https on the web browser.

[image]

But when the front end script try to connect it gives connection error as shown below. It seems the client script instead of use https , it uses wss.

[image]

The client code is simple.

[image]

I just wondering what else need to be checked to ensure the client wss can find the endpoint and start working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you investigated any of the potential problems described in the error? The error was put there to give you a pointer to what the common problems are.

Answer (score 0):

At last, i found the answer by my self. My gut feeling leads to the setup on windows server setup to enable the web socket protocol.

This is what i did to solve the issues:

(1) On my server , windows start, i typed Server Manager

[image]

(2) Then i select (2) Add Roles and features.

[image]

(3) A pop up window will appear, click next

[image]

(4) Click Next

[image]

(5) On "Select server roles", expand **Web Server (IIS)**. Expand the next **Web Server** check box again, then expand **Application Development**. Now, make sure you check the check box for **WebSocket Protocol**. Then click next.

[image]

(6) Click **Next** and then click **Install**.